# In my code setImageWithURLRequest in AFNetworking not always work

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, objective-c-blocks

Full project is here https://github.com/lerrain/ClientServerLess/tree/master/ClientServerLess

So when program starts 1st image is not displaying then next 2 images are displaying and then again one not.
Here is code with problem:

```
AAWall* wallPost = [self.wallArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.postText.delegate = self;
    cell.postText.text = wallPost.text;
    cell.postDate.text = wallPost.postDate;

    [[AAServerManager sharedManager]
    getUserWithID: wallPost.fromID
    onSucces:^(AAUser *user){               
    cell.posterName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", user.firstName, user.lastName];

    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.posterInfo.urlPhoto100];

    __weak AAWallCell *weakCell = cell;

    //Problem in this piece.

    [cell.posterImage 
    setImageWithURLRequest:urlRequest
          placeholderImage:nil
                   success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image){
                            weakCell.posterImage.image = image;
                            [weakCell layoutSubviews];
                          }
                   failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
                          {
                          }];
         }
         onFailure:^(NSError *error, NSInteger statusCode)
         {           
         }];
```

I think that I don't understand enough how blocks work.

Comment: I'd suggest adding breakpoints/basic logging in the failure cases, both for `setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure:` and `[[AAServerManager sharedManager] getUserWithId:onSuccess:onFailure:]` so you can see: 1) whether there's a failure somewhere in your processing chain; 2) if there is a failure, **where** the actual failure is; 3) details about the specific nature of the failure.  Without that kind of visibility, and without using either of those tools, it's very difficult to do much more than stab in the dark.

Comment: I added link with full code. I think that my problem is that i don't understand how blocks are working in this case. I used debugger and it didn't help me. It didn't even get in success or failure block in one of three times. I'm talking about 'setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure:'. It seems like this block even doesn't calls(or calls but not in time).

Comment: I did nothing but problem has disappeared. I don't know how.